# How we can use a custom theme in SharePoint Server 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, theme

I want to change the look and feel of my SharePoint Server 2010 site. I have used office Power font to create my custom theme as a .thmx file.

I just wanted to know how to use the custom style in SharePoint Server 2010. Like we did earlier in Office SharePoint Server 2007 by creating a theme folder.

I want a solution so if I deploy my theme into server 2010 I will not get trouble.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THMX files, exported from PowerPoint, can indeed be used by SharePoint 2010 (SPF + SPS). You can upload them into the Themes Gallery (Site Settings > Galleries > Themes).

The Themes replaces the old SP2007 Theme folder approach, and has more dynamic support for altering colors and recoloring images.

Read more about SharePoint 2010 themes in the free SharePoint eMagazine: http://information-worker.org/freemagazine.aspx

Comment: Sir Thanks but i am just wanted to know if i wanted to use a custom style. I think it will not possible for .THMX file to make custom style. so i want to create a them so will not problem while deployed to a live server. just create a theme and upload it including a branding stuff. 
Thanks & Regards,
Basant

Comment: I hope I get you right. But if you want to make custom CSS styles that take advantage of the themes in the THMX you can by using special attributes in the CSS. Custom CSS incl THMX file can be deployed through an WSP package. Check the latest issue of the free SharePoint eMagazine I linked to and you get all the details.